# FLASK After clicking on update button it shows "The requested URL was not found on the server."

Tags: python, flask

- I have a `users` table given below. I am trying to update field value `approved` for the same.

[image]

- I have defined the method in `app.py` and have written a simple update query but after clicking on the button I am facing the error `The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.`
- `app.py`

```
@app.route('/approve_student',methods = ['GET','POST'])
def approve_student(student_email):
    connection = psycopg2.connect(user="root",
                                password="root",
                                host="localhost",
                                port="5432",
                                database="proctoring")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    student_email = student_email
    sql = """ UPDATE student
            SET approved = %s
            WHERE emailid = %s"""
    cursor.execute(sql, (True, student_email))
    return redirect(url_for('admin-dashboard'))
```

- HTML

```
{% for row in data %}
...
<td>
    {% if row[5] == False %}
    <a href="{ url_for('approve_student', student_email=row[4] }" title="Approve">
    <i class="material-icons" style="font-size:16px">Approve</i></a>
...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: try to change  redirect url_for directions  and see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did,

```
@app.route('/approve_student',methods = ['GET','POST'])
def approve_student(student_email):
```

The first line suggests you do not want any parameters in the path. The second line suggests you want one parameter called `student_email`. If last is the case please try the following:

```
@app.route('/approve_student/<student_email>',methods = ['GET','POST'])
def approve_student(student_email):
```

You are also missing a few brackets in the `href` of your `<a>` tag. Try changing it to the following:

```
href="{{ url_for('approve_student', student_email=row[4]) }}"
```